# Why is the Quest 2 locked at 72 Hz in SteamVR?

Tags: steam-vr, meta-quest-2

When I use Quest Link with SteamVR on my Quest 2, the refresh rate is stuck to 72 Hz. I am using a wired link directly to my PC.

Is there a way to change that to 90 Hz or 120 Hz with the Quest 2?

Comment: I've found a bunch of reddit posts but not sure if anyone found any fixes. Links: https://www.reddit.com/r/SteamVR/comments/moc6n6/steam_vr_is_forcing_me_to_use_72hz_refresh_rate/ https://www.reddit.com/r/SteamVR/comments/kos5p1/might_be_a_stupid_question_but_how_to_i_change_my/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Steam Link](https://www.meta.com/experiences/5841245619310585/) now supports 72, 80, 90, and 120 Hz refresh rates wirelessly for the Quest 2.

This option can be found under VR Settings>General in the SteamVR settings while connected via Steam Link.

Answer (score 2):

The OP of the Reddit thread [*Stuck on 72hz link PCVR on Quest 2*](https://www.reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/12kgt1h/stuck_on_72hz_link_pcvr_on_quest_2/) received a reply from a Meta Quest Support rep:

> Hello [..] and thank you for letting us know about this! Sorry to learn you are having some issues with the graphic performance of your headset whilst using Link.
>
> In order to fix this issue, please try the following steps:
>
> 1. Open the PC app on your Computer.
> 2. Click Devices on the left side of the app then click Meta Quest.
> 3. Click Graphics Preferences then click Reset to default.
> 4. Click Save.
>
> Keep in mind, if you've previously adjusted any settings for Link with the Oculus Debug tool (including Encode Bitrate, Encode Resolution Width, Pixel Per Display), changing the graphics settings above can negatively impact your performance. To fix this, set all numerical values you changed to '0' (zero) and then restart the Desktop app.
>
> We truly hope this does the trick. If it doesn't, please do not hesitate to reach out to our team, so we can look into helping you sort this out. You can reach us directly via chat or email, right here - looking forward to it!<sup>*</sup>

However, it's not uncommon for reputable sources to give useless information :| In any case I'm not sure if that helped, because the OP replied:

> Managed to fix it, did **a complete reinstallation of the Oculus software**, which means I had to remove all the remaining files from `/AppData/` and such.
> Right now I found out what was causing the stutter on link cable: it was AMD Relive's recording (even OBS) that caused micro-stutters in the frames, which is very clunky. I have no idea why, but they work just fine with [Meta Quest] Air Link.<sup>*</sup>

The same thing, a reinstallation of the Oculus software, worked for people [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/SteamVR/comments/lyqfpm/ouest_2_stuck_at_72hz_in_steam_vr/).

Formerly, this same problem has been fixed by **setting the preferred refresh rate in the Oculus app** itself) see [here](https://communityforums.atmeta.com/t5/Oculus-Quest-2-and-Quest/Quest-2-stuck-at-72-Hz-when-using-Link/m-p/856495/highlight/true#M33960)), rather than SteamVR; by performing **SteamVR updates** (for example, [from v27 to v28](https://www.reddit.com/r/SteamVR/comments/moc6n6/steam_vr_is_forcing_me_to_use_72hz_refresh_rate/) (v27 seems to have been problematic)) and **Quest 2 firmware updates** (e.g. [updating to v40](https://communityforums.atmeta.com/t5/Get-Help/Resolved-Issue-V39-PTC-No-refresh-rate-options-above-72Hz/td-p/960103)); by **reinstalling the firmware** (see [here](https://communityforums.atmeta.com/t5/Oculus-Quest-2-and-Quest/Quest-2-stuck-to-72-hz-after-oculus-software-update-tonight/td-p/853487)); as well as **changing Nvidia GPU drivers** (see [here](https://communityforums.atmeta.com/t5/Oculus-Quest-2-and-Quest/Quest-2-stuck-at-72-Hz-when-using-Link/m-p/849485/highlight/true#M31551)).
The [current firmware version](https://www.meta.com/en-gb/help/quest/articles/whats-new/release-notes/) is v59, but the bug might have been reintroduced, so you might want to try downgrading.

<sup>* Quotes were edited for ease of reading.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using [OVR Advanced Settings](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1009850/OVR_Advanced_Settings/), if you haven't yet and check the details for the actual amount of fully rendered frames, as this hints at the reprojection-rate applied.

Meaning: if the link is too weak (signal to noise ratio too high, because of hardware-defects or interference) the projection-rate will be capped for third-party-games/platforms (as it is not guaranteed to keep this rate up and well, because they like to prioritize gaming on the in-house-platform - after all there was a reason for the name-change).

Be aware that even if you fullfil all requirements, the reprojection rate might still not be fine, e.g. because the controller isn't configured correctly, meaning it is too busy to detect its actual position - so it over-/under-compensates and effectively throws away data or can not process it in time and teherefore pushes the rendering into a very bumpy part of the road to render-heaven. As awkward as it sounds on first impression, making sure that the controller is detected correctly and you have no interference (e.g. some cheap rgb-bluetooth or proprietary wifi-direct equipment and other home-automation/mesh-devices can have impact).

If you wish to defeat the cap just for the sakes of doing it and basically silently accepting that you accept the rig will crunch itself to pieces, you can try power-up a game that is officially supported first (as long as the requirements are a given) and then start the game that is problematic.

If you run on an AMD gpu it will in all cases help to disable PCIe-SERR error-reporting (until you really need to make a full dump for debugging purposes) - it is the root cause of almost all crashes (visible and invisible). It is not actively used in the normal-modes anyway, but AMD abuses it to trigger a reset of the gpu at run-time whenever its drivers decide so, for example if it is too much lag due to resource-limits, power-fluctuations,  overheating or due to undervolting/overclocking.